# Nodejs TokenError: Code was already redeemed

Tags: node.js, passport-google-oauth

I attempted to login to my application which utilizes the Google OAuth flow. I have successfully logged in to this application in the past by going to

```
localhost:5000/auth/google
```

When I select my email, the process just hangs for about a minute and then I get the:

```
TokenError: Code was already redeemed.
```

which occurs at `localhost:5000/auth/google/callback`, which I thought perhaps that would not be a problem because it is a route that is in my `authRoutes.js` file below:

```
const passport = require('passport');

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.get(
    '/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
      scope: ['profile', 'email']
    })
  );

  app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google'));

  app.get('/api/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    // prove to whoever is
    // making request that
    // they are no longer signed in
    res.send(req.user);
  });

  app.get('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
  });
};
```

I thought I would check by going to `localhost:5000/api/current_user` which should be rendering the `googleID` and `_id` of the user as an object, but instead I get a blank screen which means I am not successfully logged in.

I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: Let me ask you this, are you using a database? If so, is your database running?

Comment: @Daniel, yes I just realized that I forgot to turn on my MongoDB database. Thank you and please post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are attempting to go through the Google OAuth flow in your local application and it just hangs, that is not a problem. Your issue was that you did not have your MongoDB database running, so it was difficult for your application to verify if this was a new user or an old user logging in based off whats stored in the database.